# How to add class name on DropdownButton component in `react-bootstrap`

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I use below components from `react-bootstrap`:

```
import { DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

When I use `DropdownButton` in my component, it creates a `<div>` with a nested `<button>`. If I set `className` on `DropdownButton` like below:

```
<DropdownButton className='myDropdown'>
```

the class name `myDropdown` will apply to the `<button>` DOM, how can I set the class name for the `<div>` DOM?

Answer (score -3):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { DropdownButton, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

export default class MyMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <DropdownButton title="Dropdownxs">
      <MenuItem href="#books">cricket</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#podcasts">Podcasts</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#">Football</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#">Hockey</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem href="#addBlog">kabadi</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(ModuleMenu, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your code. Did you solve my problem by adding class name? If yes, where is the class name defined in your code?